# Task Schedule Screensaver and end after 2 hours

Tags: batch-file, screensaver

I have a small batch which I would like to improve,

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\ACD Systems\ACDSee Pro\4.0\D3DScreenSaver\Acdsee.scr" /s
timeout /t 7200
taskkill /im "C:\Program Files (x86)\ACD Systems\ACDSee Pro\4.0\D3DScreenSaver\Acdsee.scr" /f
```

this runs the screen saver and after 2 hours end's it as the screen is off by that time.. I dont want the cpu to be active and HDD to continue displaying photos.

the timer starts after the screensaver ends!! :(

Can we somehow make the batch better, my issues are
when I move the mouse screensaver stops. which is what I want,
but the timeout command prompt is visible and I force it closed everytime, can this be automatic with auto detection of the app being closed / ended

thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\ACD Systems\ACDSee Pro\4.0\D3DScreenSaver\Acdsee.scr" /s
timeout /t 7200
taskkill /IM /F "Acdsee.scr"
```